# SELECT MAX of a group except one value

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Spark SQL and I am trying to get the records using following queries:

```
/*Select all open tasks which are not unscheduled*/
Dataset<Row> scheduledOpenTasks = sqlContext.sql(
   "SELECT * "
   + "FROM OpenTaskTable "
   + "WHERE due_date < cast('" + unscheduledDate + "' as timestamp)");

scheduledOpenTasks.createOrReplaceTempView("ScheduledOpenTaskTable");

/*Select scheduled tasks with max due_date for each csg_order_id*/
Dataset<Row> scheduledTasks = sqlContext.sql(
   "SELECT TS1.* from ScheduledOpenTaskTable AS TS1 "
   + "INNER JOIN "
   + "   (SELECT csg_order_id, MAX(due_date) AS MaxDD"
   + "   FROM ScheduledOpenTaskTable"
   + "   GROUP BY csg_order_id) AS TS2 "
   + "ON TS1.csg_order_id = TS2.csg_order_id AND TS1.due_date = TS2.MaxDD");
```

The unscheduled _date has value `4444-12-30`.

In the `OpenTaskTable`, each `csg_order_id` can have multiple `due_date`s including `unscheduled_date`. I need the `csg_order_id`s with corresponding highest `due_dates` except `unscheduled_date`.

Now, with first query, I am removing all the records which have `due_date` as `unscheduled_date`. In second query, I am retrieving all the records with max `due_date` for each `csg_order_id`.

Now comes the problem: is there any way to combine these queries as one?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after struggling for a while, finally found a way to combine the above two queries like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT OT1.* from OpenTaskTable AS OT1 INNER JOIN "
+ "(SELECT OT2.csg_order_id, MAX(OT2.due_date) AS MaxDD FROM  "
+ "(SELECT csg_order_id, due_date from OpenTaskTable WHERE due_date < cast('"+unscheduledDate+"' as timestamp)) AS OT2 "
+ "GROUP BY OT2.csg_order_id) AS OT3 "
+ "ON OT1.csg_order_id = OT3.csg_order_id AND OT1.due_date = OT3.MaxDD");
```

Explanation:
Previously, in the first query, I was retrieving data from OpenTaskTable and then feeding it to the second query. Logically, in the second query also, I am just applying more filters over the retrieved data. At the end, we are trying to get all the attributes from OpenTaskTable only.

So, for this solution I simply used the first query, as the innermost query, and then selected MAX over the records grouped by csg_order_id. And, for the outermost query, just performed an inner join to get all matching csg_order_id records from OpenTaskTable.